# chart.js で x 軸の stepSize を変更する方法

Tags: javascript, chart.js

x 座標の間隔を調整したいのですが
stepSize オプションが y 軸にしかききません

callback メソッドで表示は変えられるみたいなのですが
横軸が 100 とかになると勝手に 3 ずつとかステップされるので
その倍数以外の 5 ずつとか 10 ずつとかに変更することができません

方法はないでしょうか

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script>

var title = 'test';
var labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var datasets = [
{
    label: 'item1',
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    borderColor: '#ff8888',
},
{
    label: 'item2',
    data: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    borderColor: '#88ccff',
}
];

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: title
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 2,
          callback: function(val, index) {
            if(index % 3 == 0)
              return this.getLabelForValue(val);
            else
              return '';
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく今回のケースであれば、`stepSize`と一緒に`maxTicksLimit`を設定すればよさそうですが、データに応じて「自分が思った通り」に表示するには、グラフのデータ(`labels`, `datasets`)からこれらの値を適切に計算する必要があるかと思います。

質問のコードでx軸を2毎(1, 3, 5, ...)に表示する場合、一例として以下の様になるかと思います。

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script>

const step = 2;
const tickCounts = (labels, step) => (Math.round(labels.length / step));

var title = 'test';
var labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var datasets = [
{
    label: 'item1',
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    borderColor: '#ff8888',
},
{
    label: 'item2',
    data: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    borderColor: '#88ccff',
}
];

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: title
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: tickCounts(labels, step),
          stepSize: step,
          callback: function(val, index) {
            if(index % 3 == 0)
              return this.getLabelForValue(val);
            else
              return '';
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>
```

Comment: maxTicksLimit というのがあるんですね。試しに1000とかにしてみたらステップ制御できたので callback の中で何とでもできそうです！